# match element ids in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, mysql

What I want to do is "When the user clicks a name in a table, the corresponding details should be shown. If the user clicks his/her name again, the detailed information should be hidden."
The table is like this:

```
Name                 Details
aaa kkk             Date of Birth: 2016-05-06  Email:aaa@gmail.com
Elliot Botwright    Date of Birth: 1975-08-19  Email:Elliot.Botwright@gdu.edu.au
```

Currently I'm trying to assign increment ids for table contents using

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $i=1;
    echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Details</th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr><td id='names'.$i.''>" . $row['Name']. "</td><td  id='details'.$i.''>Date of Birth: ". $row['DOB']. "<br>Email: ".$row['Email']."</td></tr>";
    $i++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    }
And then in jQuery:
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^=details]').hide();
    $('[id^=names]').click(function(){
    var number = $(this).attr("id");
    number = number.replace('names', '');
    if($('[id=details'.number.']').is(':hidden')) {$('[id=details'.number.']').show();}
    else{($('[id=details'.number.']').hide();}
    });
    });
</script>
```

I use `$('[id^=details]').hide();` to hide details, it works. And then I try to get id of clicked name using `var number = $(this).attr("id");` and cut the part of `names`. Then I try to hide and display the detail contents that share the same number with the clicked name. But this part does not work and makes all jQuery codes invalid. Would you please help me?

Comment: sorry, new to stack overflow and don't know how to upload images or code. Maybe anyone could firs tell me that?

Comment: Try substituting `+` for `.` as concatenating operator at `javascript`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mghy0svw/